# Exclude User Group from Sale

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

Is there a way to exclude a User Group from a sale?

We have a trade user account that applies a flat 20% discount across all products but we're trying to run a different sale for all customers on a few products.

The issue is any customer within the trade user group is getting the flat 20% discount and the further 25% on these specific products.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Would it be an option for you to create adjusters?